# Problem uploading a .json file containing list of json objects to Azure CosmosDB using Python script

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to upload a .json file containing list of json objects to Azure CosmosDB using a python script.

I am referring the following link https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-python-getting-started for uploading a json file that contains a list of JSON objects. The Azure cosmos client libraries used here only support sending a single json object at a time, but I would like to send a list of json objects in a single request.

This is the json format I want to send

```
    [{
    'id': 'server1',
    'Web Site': 0,
    'Cloud Service': 0,
    'Virtual Machine': 0,
    'message': 'Hello World from Server 1!'
    },
    {
    'id': 'server2',
    'Web Site': 0,
    'Cloud Service': 0,
    'Virtual Machine': 0,
    'message': 'Hello World from Server 1!'
    }]
```

This is the error I got

```
nayana@nayana-HP-Notebook:~/Azure$ python3 Upload\ to\ azure\ cosmo.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Upload to azure cosmo.py", line 52, in <module>
    'message': 'Hello World from Server 2!'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/azure/cosmos/cosmos_client.py", line 1023, in CreateItem
    collection_id, document, path = self._GetContainerIdWithPathForItem(database_or_Container_link, document, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/azure/cosmos/cosmos_client.py", line 1080, in _GetContainerIdWithPathForItem
    CosmosClient.__ValidateResource(document)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/azure/cosmos/cosmos_client.py", line 2854, in __ValidateResource
    id = resource.get('id')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I installed the azure-cosmos package using **pip3 install azure-cosmos** that contains the cosmos_client.py

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

As i know, if you use the CreateItem method in the python sdk, you could only create one single  document every time. There are no api calls to insert multiple documents at once.(Please see this thread:[Cosmos DB - Insert Multiple Records with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962800/cosmos-db-insert-multiple-records-with-python))

Surely,you may consider [bulk import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-overview). However, python lib is not supported yet.Only [.net and java lib](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-overview) could be found on the official document.

So,i'm afraid that you should load your own json file and do the insert actions in the loop.

Of course, you could load json files into cosmos db directly by using [Cosmos db Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data).

[image]

---

Update Answer:

Migration Tool can't be touched for MAC or LINUX which is mentioned in this feedback [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/16049215-add-import-tooling-support-for-mac-linux).You could vote up it to push the progress of such features.

The official suggestion is still using Bulk Executor Library for Java and .NET core. If you have to use python, you could refer to this unofficial [blog](http://link:https://blog.siliconvalve.com/2018/11/19/bulk-insert-entities-into-cosmos-db-using-python/)  to get some clues.

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion about Data Migration Tool but I want this application on a Linux based machine. The pre-compiled files we get are .exe. I tried downloading Wine to execute the .exe file but it gives an error saying  ** doesn't have entry point, it cannot be executed **

Comment: Thank you, for the suggestion, and about the blog link you mentioned it directs to **about:blank#blocked** and is not accessible.